# Is there a way to color code some of folders in Mail.app?

Tags: macos, mac, apple-mail

Is there a way to color code some of folders in Mail.app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this which is some what close to what I was looking for:

[Tasty OS X Software & Widgets's - Flagit!](http://www.tastyapps.com/)

Comment: This can also be done with http://www.indev.ca/MailTags.html, but your question was about coloring folders, which can't be done as fideli correctly points out.

Comment: right, that's why i said that's the closest that I could fine, I'm not very happy as I need to mark folders not messages

Answer (score 0):

I looked around for various extensions and have concluded that it's not possible.